# GAPI(Google API) Drive. Запрос файлов по атрибуту appProperties не работает

Tags: javascript, http, rest, google-drive

Параметры запроса:

```
"q": "appProperties has {key='hah' and value='vah'}",
"fields": "files(id,name,appProperties)"
```

Пробуя запрос files.list в окружении доков Google API (который Try it), запрос проходит и данные возвращаются корректные.

Пытаясь выполнить тот же запрос из приложения, то запрос проходит, но получаю пустой список файлов:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": []
}
```

Да, приходит так же заголовок `"incompleteSearch": false`, но в других запросах даже с таким заголовком данные приходят корректно (возможно стоит использовать nextPageToken?). Притом если тот же запрос делать через GAPI (а не через запрос HTTP, XHR), то просто придет пустой список файлов.

С другими запросами проблем нет. Права выданы все (пока для теста). Другие запросы корректно. Запрос делается напрямую из браузера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все очень просто. appProperties является **приватным** полем и доступно только приложению, которое его добавило.

В данном случае Googld API Doc являлось одним приложением, а мое - другим. Поэтому я не мог получить данные , которые были нужны, ибо не думал, что гугл доки считаются за другое приложение(хотя это и логично).

Внедрив функцию добавления этих аттрибутов из приложения при создании/обновлении файла - все заработало